# Binary XML file line #415: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I get inflater error in my activity code
I referred this web site, i cannot get solution
**My xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/projectcommends_combine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.servicebellpartner.Fragment.ProjectComments"
    tools:layout="@layout/project_comments"></fragment></RelativeLayout>
```

**My activity code:**

```
public class OrderDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.order_detail);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ProjectComments projectComments = new ProjectComments(orderid);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.projectcommends_combine, projectComments);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

**My Fragment code:**

```
public class ProjectComments extends Fragment {
private String orderid;
public ProjectComments(String orderid){
    this.orderid = orderid;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_comments, container, false);
    return view;
}}
```

**I get below error in run the app**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.servicebellpartner/com.servicebellpartner.Activity.OrderDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #415: Error inflating class fragment
```

Please any one give solution and explanation.

Comment: Please... share whole stack trace...

Comment: what is stack trace?

Comment: @vinothkumar: using Fragment from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: I am using import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is missing the closing tag for u'r relative layout.
Also the fragment has no public parameterless constructor .
So it can not instantiated by the framework.

Comment: Fragment has no public parameterless constructor? Please give code

Comment: Maybe you should spend some time to study some very basic programming tutorials? Your fragment constructor should be: public ProjectComments().
Also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984054/android-fragments-is-empty-constructor-really-required